# Norton installation: temporary files ask for execution permission

Tags: windows-10, norton-internet-security

I click on the Norton installation file and no “Windows user account control” pops up, instead a Norton installation windows starts and displays that product is downloading. After a while “windows user account control” pops up asking to install files I did not download. I press “no” and installation obviously gets aborted. I do not want to execute files I did not download directly. Is there an offline installer available? Norton website offers no offline installer file.
Thanks

Comment: If you find an offline installer, the first thing it's going to want to do is update itself, then update its definitions twice a day. At some point you're going to have to let it do its job.

Comment: It is not about updating itself it is about granting administrator rights to the temporary files I did not download.

Comment: I'm really not sure what your issue is. You launched Norton's installer, let it install.

Comment: Why do you think downloading something explicitly is safer than letting a program do its job automatically? You either trust the vendor or not. If you don't, why would downloading an offline installer be any safer?

Comment: Good question. Maybe I just feel more safety if I grant administrator rights to an exe file I download directly rather then letting this exe download temporary files which prompt  a “user account control” windows asking for “yes”

Comment: You're going to have to grant Norton (or any antivirus/security package) sweeping rights to your entire machine. It will need those to do its job. If you're paranoid about that, you have to pick one you trust,.. or stop going on the interwebz, because there's a whole lot nastier out there than a legitimate security package from a known-good company.